# How to open a found file with vi? Piping 'find' output to vi

Tags: vim, console, find

I have a file, `/home/user/important.txt`. To find it, I use:

```
find /home/user -type f -name 'important'
```

Then, I want to open the file in the [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) editor using a pipe.

How can I do this?

Something like

```
find /home/user -type f -name 'important' | vi
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because `vim` has a `:find` command, so this is the most pointless use of `find` there is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add * wildcard after 'important', also you can use the following command:

```
vim $(find /home/user -name "important*")
```

Comment: You might want to add `-print` because sometimes find just hangs there without it

Comment: @Serg print is the default action, so no.

Comment: this doesn't work if the file names have spaced

Comment: @retorquere Just put command substitution in double quotes if the file name contains spaces. For example: vim "$(find /home/user -name "important*")"

Comment: Doesn't work if it returns multiple files. I now do `vim $(find . -name "important*" -print0 | quote0)`, where quote0 is https://gist.github.com/c3ce8d39c371c75705c1c3a22005890d

Answer (score 10):

You can use `-exec` along with `find`. Use the following command:

```
find /home/user -type f -name 'important' -exec vi {} \;
```

Comment: Can you please explain last symbols, `{} \;` what they mean?

Comment: @micgeronimo That's part of the `exec` syntax. `{}` will be replaced with the name of the filename, and `\;` is used to indicate that the end of the command for `exec`.

Comment: Nice tip. But there is another question - I have found 100 files and vim open them one by one after current file become closed. How to cancel whole command and exit to the shell instead of typing :q on each file or kill terminal. Thanks

Comment: @alexche8  find /home/user -type f -name 'important' -exec vi -p {} +
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/how-do-i-open-multiple-files-from-find-each-in-a-separate-tab-in-vim

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
find ./ -name 'important.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 vi
```

This works, and it's simple.

If you don't need a pipe then you can try this:

```
find ./ -name 'important.txt' -exec vi {} \;
```

Comment: @Peter Mortensen

is -print0 and -0 really required ?

Comment: does not work as expected - terminal hangs after quitting vi

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get the output of the find command (i.e. the list of files) in vim, then the following will have vim read from find's output:

```
find /home/user -type f -name 'important' | vi -
```

---

If you wish to open the files themselves, then xargs and find's -exec action are good options, as mentioned by other answers.

However, for the -exec action you are much better off using the following syntax:

```
find /home/user -type f -name 'important' -exec vi {} +
```

The distinction between "\;" and "+" at the end of the command is as follows:

With "\;" an instance of vim will be opened for each file that is found. This means that if 20 files are found, you will have to close vim 20 times to get back to the shell and you cannot move between the files within vim.

With "+", a single instance of vim will be opened with all of the found files. This means that you can move back and forth between the files as buffers and when you are done, there is only one instance of vim to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

`locate` is simple as so:

`locate -0 important.txt | xargs -0 vi`

Answer (score 1):

You could use first choice:

```
find ./ -name 'important' -print0 | xargs -0 vi
```

or as a second choice:

```
find /home/user -type f -name 'important' -exec vi {} \;
```

Please note, the `xargs` command can correctly handle the spaces within the file names found by the `find` command without you having to worrying about unexpected outcomes.

and avoid command substitution like following:

```
vim $(find /home/user -name "important*")
```

This is because in most cases, you simply don't know how many results(files) you are expecting or whether those file names have spaces in them to avoid unwanted results due to spaces.